# there is a vertical line of printing in my windows phone app screen, what is that?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone dev. just downloaded an example project, ran it and found there is a line on the right of the screen like memory info printing. what is that? Can anyone let me know how to turn it off? I can not post the screenshot. please see the link below:
http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2012/11/3/how-to-get-c-winrt-in-a-windows-phone-8-application#disqus_thread

the screenshot is the first image on that article. click it to zoom in. you can see there is a vertical line on the right, like memory printing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [frame rate counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg588380%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). To turn it off, open App.xaml.cs file and in the constructor, set `EnableFrameRateCounter` to `false`. It is set to `true` by default :

```
// Display the current frame rate counters.
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = false;
```

Another info, it is only displayed in debugging mode. Because line of code to enable frame rate counter resides inside `if (Debugger.IsAttached)` block. Your final application won't have those weird numbers printed on screen.